# Dovecot is not working

Tags: centos, email-server, dovecot

I'm having a server. The server information I've given below.

```
Linux host.com 2.6.32-531.29.2.lve1.3.11.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Dec 18 06:49:17 EST 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

When I was trying to restart Dovecot IMAP and POP. It got failed and showing following error.

```
Jul 23 01:30:41 platinum dovecot: imap-login: Fatal: master: service(imap-login): child 747903 returned error 127
Jul 23 01:30:41 platinum dovecot: pop3-login: Fatal: master: service(pop3-login): child 747902 returned error 127
Jul 23 01:30:40 platinum dovecot: master: Error: service(imap-login): command startup failed, throttling for 2 secs
Jul 23 01:30:40 platinum dovecot: master: Error: service(pop3-login): command startup failed, throttling for 2 secs
Jul 23 01:30:39 platinum dovecot: master: Warning: /selinux is no longer mounted. See http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Mountpoints
```

I've read some manual, tried to ignore this mounted file. However it is still not working. May i know how I can solve this issue ?

After manual restart following is logs

```
Jul 23 02:19:43 platinum dovecot: master: Error: service(imap-login): command startup failed, throttling for 2 secs
Jul 23 02:19:44 platinum dovecot: pop3-login: Fatal: master: service(pop3-login): child 805429 returned error 127
Jul 23 02:19:44 platinum dovecot: imap-login: Fatal: master: service(imap-login): child 805430 returned error 127
Jul 23 02:20:11 platinum dovecot: imap-login: Error: dovecot/imap-login: error while loading shared libraries: librt.so.1: failed to map segment from shared object: Cannot allocate memory
Jul 23 02:20:11 platinum dovecot: imap-login: Error: dovecot/imap-login: error while loading shared libraries: librt.so.1: failed to map segment from shared object: Cannot allocate memory
Jul 23 02:20:11 platinum dovecot: imap-login: Fatal: master: service(imap-login): child 806007 returned error 127
Jul 23 02:20:11 platinum dovecot: master: Error: service(imap-login): command startup failed, throttling for 4 secs
Jul 23 02:21:24 platinum dovecot: imap-login: Error: dovecot/imap-login: error while loading shared libraries: librt.so.1: failed to map segment from shared object: Cannot allocate memory
Jul 23 02:21:24 platinum dovecot: master: Error: service(imap-login): command startup failed, throttling for 8 secs
Jul 23 02:21:24 platinum dovecot: imap-login: Fatal: master: service(imap-login): child 807199 returned error 127
```

Even if from the following solution, I got the same error. 
Update :

```
Jul 23 02:42:08 platinum dovecot: master: Error: service(imap-login): command startup failed, throttling for 2 secs
Jul 23 02:42:08 platinum dovecot: master: Error: service(pop3-login): command startup failed, throttling for 2 secs
Jul 23 02:42:05 platinum dovecot: master: Warning: /selinux is no longer mounted. See http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Mountpoints
Jul 23 02:42:05 platinum dovecot: master: Warning: /var/named/chroot/etc/named.conf is no longer mounted. See http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Mountpoints
Jul 23 02:42:05 platinum dovecot: master: Warning: /var/named/chroot/var/named is no longer mounted. See http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Mountpoints
```

After un-mounting the /selinux I found following errors.

```
Jul 23 03:00:45 platinum dovecot: pop3-login: Fatal: master: service(pop3-login): child 847454 returned error 127
Jul 23 03:00:45 platinum dovecot: imap-login: Fatal: master: service(imap-login): child 847450 returned error 127
Jul 23 03:00:45 platinum dovecot: pop3-login: Fatal: master: service(pop3-login): child 847449 returned error 127
Jul 23 03:00:45 platinum dovecot: pop3-login: Error: dovecot/pop3-login: error while loading shared libraries: librt.so.1: failed to map segment from shared object: Cannot allocate memory
Jul 23 03:00:45 platinum dovecot: pop3-login: Error: dovecot/pop3-login: error while loading shared libraries: librt.so.1: failed to map segment from shared object: Cannot allocate memory
```

Comment: Whst distro is this on?

Comment: Im using CentOS

Comment: And there is free memory available for dovecot?

Comment: Have you made the [change suggested in the answer by Hawkeye](http://serverfault.com/a/707837/267016)? I don't see it in your listed configuration.

Comment: Okay Issue resolved. I've increased the size. Thank you all :)

Answer (score 1):

From the information you provided, I'm assuming that you are most probably running RHEL 6 or CentOS 6.

Perhaps you should try starting the dovecot service manually first and post the log again.

--Update

Ok. These steps should fix the problem.

1. Edit the file using the command `vi /etc/dovecot.conf`
2. Find the line which has `login_process_size`
3. Uncomment it and modify it to `login_process_size = 64`
4. Save the file and start the service with `service dovecot stop` and `service dovecot start`

I found this solution from [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/rhel-dovecot-error-while-loading-shared-libraries.html).

Comment: No Didn't started any service manually.

Comment: Try starting the dovecot service using `service dovecot start` and later post the output of `tail /var/log/upstart/dovecot.log`

Comment: I've updated the Question.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post `doveconf -n` output?

Also, if you saw:

`Jul 23 01:30:39 platinum dovecot: master: Warning: /selinux is no longer mounted. See http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Mountpoints`

you should use `doveadm mount list` to list all partitions (the one used by dovecot shoud have ! at the begining) and `doveadm mount remove /selinux`. That might solve your problem.

Comment: Updated please check

Comment: Jul 23 02:57:40 platinum dovecot: imap-login: Fatal: master: service(imap-login): child 844203 returned error 127
Jul 23 02:57:40 platinum dovecot: imap-login: Fatal: master: service(imap-login): child 844207 returned error 127
Jul 23 02:57:40 platinum dovecot: pop3-login: Fatal: master: service(pop3-login): child 844202 returned error 127
Jul 23 02:57:39 platinum dovecot: master: Error: service(imap-login): command startup failed, throttling for 2 secs
Jul 23 02:57:39 platinum dovecot: master: Error: service(pop3-login): command startup failed, throttling for 2 secs

Comment: Have you tried to disable SELinux?

Comment: Nop. I can't Disable SELinux.

Comment: If you can't disable SELinux, you should set up more verbose dovecot logs. Set `mail_debug = yes` in /etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-logging.conf.